# Finding $f(1)$ of general biquadratic polynomial whose $|f(\iota)|$ is given.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> **Question:** Let $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ with real coefficients and real roots. If $|f(\iota)|=1$.
>   Find the value of $a+b+c+d$.

Since $a+b+c+d=f(1)-1$. Finding $f(1)$ would be quite helpful and it is the shortest way to find the answer (purely my reasoning). I got a feeling that $f(1)=1$ due to some reason. Maybe because $|f(\iota)|=1$ and that $f(1)=|f(1)|$ if $f(1)$ will be positive. It doesn't make sense though.

Here is the obvious approach which I don't like and also am stuck at a point.

> $f(\iota)=(1-b+d)+(c-a)\iota$
>   So,$|f(\iota)|=\sqrt{(1-b+d)^2+(c-a)^2}$
>   Which gives, $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-2b+2d-2bd-2ac=0$
>   This equation doesn't add anything.

I don't like these usual approaches to the question.
I first want you to consider the initial short approach. If this question is solvable like that then give me some hint otherwise tell me how to proceed further from the equation I produced in $a,b,c,d$

Comment: Well $\iota=\sqrt{-1}$. I have read it in quite a no. of books. Our teachers too prefer to use $\iota$ over $i$

Comment: Maybe thats because of difference in countries. Here everyone uses $\iota$

Comment: Have a look at this site, too (many countries, not just one). Or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963406/notation-for-complex-numbers) perhaps. I haven't seen iota, but always $i$. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387820/a-proper-definition-of-i-the-imaginary-unit). But indeed, why not iota....

Comment: Well I have seen people arguing over it too.

Comment: Its ok. Seems like all other countries use $i$ except for India. I made it clear that I mean $\sqrt{-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $f(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)$, $x_i$ real.
$$1=|f(i)|^2=|(i-x_1)(i-x_2)(i-x_3)(i-x_4)|^2=(x_1^2+1)(x_2^2+1)(x_3^2+1)(x_4^2+1)\geq 1$$

Equality holds, so $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=0$, so $a=b=c=d=0$, and their sum is $0$.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Great. I don't know that "Equality holds" is really the best explanation for the punchline; the point is that _each_ $x_j^2+1$ is $\ge 1$, hence equality holds in _each_ inequality $x_j^1+1\ge1$.